# iPhone Application build copies <Prefix_filename>.pch.gch

Tags: iphone, xcode, precompiled-headers

I large (12 mb) Prefix.pch.gch file is being copied to my final iPhone application. It does **not** exist in the project and only shows up in the build log. It adds quite a bit to my otherwise small application size. Any suggestions for stopping xcode from copying it? Does anyone know what it is? I did a little research, and it looks like a cache file for a precompiled header, but I couldn't find anything as to why its 12 mb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889445/how-to-stop-huge-prefix-pch-gch-file-from-being-copied-into-application-bundle/3450472#3450472) for a possible cause. If that's it, it should be easy to fix.