# Release Build Error

Tags: ios

I've searched all the keywords I can think of but haven't found a response that solves my issue. Unfortunately I've caved and decided to post.

I'm getting an error when performing release builds. Everything builds fine normally, but the moment I build for profiling or archiving, I get the following error:

```
ProcessPCH "/Users/richiegravedigga/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Words_and_Pictures_D&D-eqhdxksfeleytufyvihmrpzftcue/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/Prefix-drwdxbmsmxqipefcjlsdqbvxksuv/Prefix.pch.gch" "Words and Pictures : Drag and Drop - HD/Prefix.pch" normal i386 c com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42
cd "/Users/richiegravedigga/Dropbox/iphone_dev/iOS Projects/WOWD&D/WOWD&D"
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -x c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -DNDEBUG -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fvisibility=hidden -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40300 -iquote "/Users/richiegravedigga/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Words_and_Pictures_D&D-eqhdxksfeleytufyvihmrpzftcue/Build/Intermediates/Words and Pictures D&D.build/Distribution-iphonesimulator/Words and Pictures : Drag and Drop - HD.build/Words and Pictures : Drag and Drop - HD-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Users/richiegravedigga/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Words_and_Pictures_D&D-eqhdxksfeleytufyvihmrpzftcue/Build/Intermediates/Words and Pictures D&D.build/Distribution-iphonesimulator/Words and Pictures : Drag and Drop - HD.build/Words and Pictures : Drag and Drop - HD-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/richiegravedigga/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Words_and_Pictures_D&D-eqhdxksfeleytufyvihmrpzftcue/Build/Intermediates/Words and Pictures D&D.build/Distribution-iphonesimulator/Words and Pictures : Drag and Drop - HD.build/Words and Pictures : Drag and Drop - HD-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Users/richiegravedigga/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Words_and_Pictures_D&D-eqhdxksfeleytufyvihmrpzftcue/Build/Intermediates/Words and Pictures D&D.build/Distribution-iphonesimulator/Words and Pictures : Drag and Drop - HD.build/Words and Pictures : Drag and Drop - HD-project-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/richiegravedigga/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Words_and_Pictures_D&D-eqhdxksfeleytufyvihmrpzftcue/Build/Products/Distribution-iphonesimulator/include" "-I/Users/richiegravedigga/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Words_and_Pictures_D&D-eqhdxksfeleytufyvihmrpzftcue/Build/Intermediates/Words and Pictures D&D.build/Distribution-iphonesimulator/Words and Pictures : Drag and Drop - HD.build/DerivedSources/i386" "-I/Users/richiegravedigga/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Words_and_Pictures_D&D-eqhdxksfeleytufyvihmrpzftcue/Build/Intermediates/Words and Pictures D&D.build/Distribution-iphonesimulator/Words and Pictures : Drag and Drop - HD.build/DerivedSources" DEBUG "-F/Users/richiegravedigga/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Words_and_Pictures_D&D-eqhdxksfeleytufyvihmrpzftcue/Build/Products/Distribution-iphonesimulator" -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -c "/Users/richiegravedigga/Dropbox/iphone_dev/iOS Projects/WOWD&D/WOWD&D/Words and Pictures : Drag and Drop - HD/Prefix.pch" -o "/Users/richiegravedigga/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Words_and_Pictures_D&D-eqhdxksfeleytufyvihmrpzftcue/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/Prefix-drwdxbmsmxqipefcjlsdqbvxksuv/Prefix.pch.gch"

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

So far I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248520/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-code-1-iphone), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490847/developer-platforms-iphonesimulator-platform-developer-usr-bin-gcc-4-2-failed-wi) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166408/developer-platforms-iphonesimulator-platform-developer-usr-bin-gcc-4-2-failed-wi), among other articles, but none of them have worked. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: No specific error message is posted and only fails on profiling/archiving. You should check the preprocessor macros on that pch.

Comment: Hi Jano. Thanks for your reply. Can you elaborate a bit for me? As far as I know the pch file is still the default and hasn't changed.

Comment: I can't unfortunately. If there is no error message I can only suggest to look into it. It may have conditional macros that you need and are only enabled on a release/debug build. Post your Prefix.pch, and see also this for a possible different problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889445/how-to-stop-huge-prefix-pch-gch-file-from-being-copied-into-application-bundle/3450472#3450472

Comment: can you post the full compilation transcript from the ProcessPCH onwards please?